# Chart.js blurs when resizing

Tags: javascript, html, css, canvas, charts

I want to change chart size via pulldown menu.

The chart is placed in the graphearea div.

```
<div class="grapharea" >
        <canvas id="myChartA" class="myChart"></canvas>
</div>
```

The size of "myChart" class is 100%. Therefore, if the size of "graphearea" changes, the size of myChat also changes.

The size of "graphearea" will be changed columnSizeSet function, and  size of ".myChart" will be reset.

```
function columnSizeSet() {
     obj = document.setCol.sizeOfCol;
     index = obj.selectedIndex;
     width = obj.options[index].value;
     console.log('width', width);
     $('.grapharea').css('width', width);
     $('.myChart').css('width','100%');
     $('.myChart').css('height', '100%');
     myChartA.update();
}
```

Finally, myChartA is updated.

But, it will not work what I want.

First, chart is shown normally. select the chart size relative to the browser width.
[image]

Next, select the chart size relative to the browser width.　Chart was resized　however the chart is blurred.
[image]

If I changed the size of browse window, it become clearly.

[image]

Why don't it draw beautifully from the beginning when I change the size?
Chartjs's canvas has a drawing buffer and only the buffer size is changed in the above way. I guess that the buffer was cleared and redrawn when the window was resized.

How to control the redraw ?

I had implemented it as Chart.js Option.

```
responsive: true,
maintainAspectRatio: true,
```

Is it not work on the redraw?

I had source code in [CODE Pen](https://codepen.io/nobuyuki-kukimoto-kukimoto/pen/vYBwWLV).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the [Chart.js docs](https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/general/responsive.html):

> The chart can also be programmatically resized by modifying the
>   container size:
>
> chart.canvas.parentNode.style.height = '128px';
>   chart.canvas.parentNode.style.width = '128px';

Answer (score -1):

I found out to solve problems.
Wrong:

```
 <div class="grapharea">
```

Correct:

```
<div class="grapharea" style="position: relative;">
```